# How I can have different values and different labels at graphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

I am using a linechart at graphael. My datapoints are dates,which are not recognisable by the graphael. So I have represented every date, using 1,2,3 ....

The fact is that I need to display dates at my chart, as the x axis labels. How I can do that? I tried the label property, but it does not working.

My code is shown below:

```
    var lines = r.linechart(30, 30, 600, 440,[[1,2,3,4,5]],[[100,150,130,85,100]], {axisxstep : 20,nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true }).hoverColumn(function () {
        this.tags = r.set();

        for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
            this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 160, 10).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
        }
    }, function () {
        this.tags && this.tags.remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/777wH/). You have to change the attribute of each label (date for us) inside chartobject:

```
var lineChart = r.linechart(0, 0, 200, 250, xValues, yValues1, {
    smooth: true,
    colors: ['#F00', '#0F0', '#FF0'],
    symbol: 'circle',
    axis: '0 0 1 1'
});

for (var i = 0; i < lineChart.axis[0].text.items.length; i++) {
    var label = lineChart.axis[0].text.items[i];
    var originalDate = new Date(parseInt(label.attr('text'), 10));
    var newText = originalDate.getDate() + "/" + (originalDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (originalDate.getFullYear());

    label.rotate(60);
    label.attr({
        'text': newText
    });
}
```

Also, the data for graphael can only be numerical type to plot the graph, we have to create a `Date` object for each label in x like this:

```
var xValues = [
    new Date("01/05/2014"),
    new Date("01/06/2014"),
    new Date("01/07/2014"),
    new Date("01/08/2014"),
    new Date("01/09/2014"),
    new Date("01/10/2014"),
    new Date("01/11/2014"),
    new Date("01/12/2014"),
    new Date("01/13/2014")
];
```